# Convert existing List into a json/text file so moving forward read the data from that file to generate the List

Tags: android, list, kotlin, any

How do I change this `List<Any>` into text/json file and then read it?
As this FAQ question and answer will be hardcoded, so, I do not want it to be set directly inside my fragment. I'm planning to put the info into assets file, then read it from there to generate the `List`

My `List<Any>`

```
val list: List<Any> = arrayListOf(
        "General",
        FAQ(faqQuestion = "ABC?", faqAnswer = "QWERTY", expanded = false),
        FAQ(faqQuestion = "DEF?", faqAnswer = "ZXCVBN", expanded = false),
        "Troubleshooting",
        FAQ(faqQuestion = "ZXC?", faqAnswer = "POIUYT", expanded = false)
)
```

I do not know how to convert this into `JSON` or text file and successfully export it into this `List`.

What I tried so far are:

`faq.json`

```
[
  "General",
  {
    "expanded":false,
    "faqQuestion":"ABC?",
    "faqAnswer":"QWERTY"
  },
  {
    "expanded":false,
    "faqQuestion":"DEF?",
    "faqAnswer":"ZXCVBN"
  }
]
```

Text file `faq.txt`

```
"General",
FAQ(faqQuestion = "ABC?", faqAnswer = "QWERTY", expanded = false),
FAQ(faqQuestion = "DEF?", faqAnswer = "ZXCVBN", expanded = false),
"Troubleshooting",
FAQ(faqQuestion = "ZXC?", faqAnswer = "POIUYT", expanded = false)
```

Code to get from assets: Text

```
fun loadFromAsset(fileName: String, context: Context): Any? {
    val any: Any
    try {
        val ins = context.getAssets().open(fileName)
        val size = ins.available()
        val buffer = ByteArray(size)
        ins.read(buffer)
        ins.close()
        any = String(buffer, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }

    return any
}

var list: List<Any>?
loadFromAsset("faq.txt", requireContext())?.let {
    list = arrayListOf(it)
}
```

JSON

```
fun loadFromAsset(fileName: String, context: Context): String? {
    var json: String? = null
    try {
        val ins = context.getAssets().open(filename)
        val size = ins.available()
        val buffer = ByteArray(size)
        ins.read(buffer)
        ins.close()
        json = String(buffer, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }

    return json
}

val list: List<Any> = Gson().fromJson(loadFromAsset("faq.json", requireContext()), Array<Any>::class.java).asList()
```

Both way cannot get as per the original `List<Any>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your json contains only `String` and `FAQ` elements

```
val list: List<Any> = gson.fromJson(json, JsonArray::class.java).map {
    when (it) {
        is JsonPrimitive -> it.asString as Any
        else -> gson.fromJson(it, FAQ::class.java) as Any
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was trying to do. I'm relatively new, so didn't knew about map and such things.